# System User not getting manage_pages permission from page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made a system user and he has permissions of manage_pages.

Then from his access token I made a call to this URL

```
me/accounts
```

Then the pages were listed below with their access tokens.

Then those access tokens didn't have manage_pages permission.

Problem:
I need manage_pages permission on those page access tokens.

Comment: What do you mean by “system user”? And page access tokens don’t “have” manage_pages permission, user access tokens do. And the user access token you are using clearly includes that permission already – because otherwise you would not get _anything_ from `/me/accounts` to begin with.

Comment: system user is the user created from business manager API